# Adding file geodatabase attachments to features using QGIS

Tags: qgis, file-geodatabase, attachments

Is it possible to add attachments (PDFs, Word documents, etc) to features in QGIS (and not via a hyperlink)?

An attachment, as in a binary file that is [stored in a file geodatabase](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/editing-attributes/adding-attachments-to-features.htm), rather than a hyperlink.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "not via a hyperlink". Is it the document must be saved into the datasource (as in portable in a single file) or is it about the document must be shown embedded in the QGIS user interface.

Comment: You can add images and webpages (not sure if you include these as documents...) to features by right-clicking your layer and then accessing `Properties > Fields`. In the **Edit widget** column, click the default *Text Edit* button and select **External Resource**. Here you can add images/webpages which can be viewed in the *Attribute Table*.

Comment: Are you perhaps wanting to store attachments in a file geodatabase?

Comment: Yes, it can be done in ArcMap ( http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/editing-attributes/adding-attachments-to-features.htm ), but then with a similar tool in QGIS.

Comment: Is a similar tool available in QGIS to store attachments in a file geodatabase?